# What is a yum package conflict?

Tags: mysql, centos, package, conflict

When running the transaction check to install mysql i'm getting:

Processing Conflict: mysql55-5.5.29-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts mysql < 5.5

I guess this means i'm attempting to install a package called mysql55-5.5.29-1.w6.x86_64 on to a system with mysql already installed but somehow there is a conflict?

yum says that mysql isn't installed so it was installed without using the repositories. In that case how does yum know there is confict?

it would be good to better under what 'confict' means.

Answer (score 1):

There are many online yum repo available and all are free opensource contribute. So source packages are compiled with different options in each repo. So when we add 2 or more yum repo at a time, it may happen that 2 or more packages are of same version are selected and we get a conflict error.

In your case you added some repo which is providing mysql 5.5 which is already available with some other name in some other repo or already installed but new mysql package is selected by yum for any other package as dependency. Try removing one of the repo or try installing it as yum install mysql-5.5*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : yum list | grep mysql. It will list mysql in different packages, then you can make a decision to remove one of them and install mysql again.